# Convert lists within a data frame into vectors

Tags: r, list, vector

I have the following data frame:

```
Offer ID    Item ID  
162840  56A340942123, 902G569800234  
162841  96A3403718213, 872M569814535, M235481980234, 890TG56248191  
162842  H7901230913592
```

Offer ID is a character vector, and Item ID is a list. Here, Item ID has 3 elements- one for each row.

Is it possible to convert Item ID into a vector from a list so that I can reference each Item ID within the same row separately?

I'm relatively new to R and I've tried unlist, do.call,  and paste and they all mess up the dimensions of my data frame.

Note: I don't want to split them into sublists.

ETA: Output of `dput`-

```
structure(list(Col1 = c(162840L, 162841L, 162842L, 162843L, 162845L, 
162847L, 162849L), Col2 = structure(list(`1` = c("137089", "668552", 
"346129"), `4` = c("442054", "479934", "58316"), `7` = c("149298", 
"533977", "598069"), `10` = c("898134", "614982", "581007", "570515"
), `14` = c("93015", "252103", "639482", "226594", "64429"), 
    `19` = c("328971", "604454", "603078"), `22` = "93774"), .Names = c("1", 
"4", "7", "10", "14", "19", "22"))), .Names = c("Col1", "Col2"
), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = "data.frame")
```

Expected Output:

```
Offer ID    Item ID1    Item ID2    Item ID3    Item ID4  
168240      137089      668552      346129  
162841      442054      479934      58316  
162842      149298      533977      598069  
162843      898134      614982      581007      570515
```

Comment: Use `cSplit(df1, "item ID", ",", "long")`

Comment: @akrun Are you referring to `splitstackshape::cSplit`? You really should qualify the source of non-standard functions.

Comment: What exactly is your expected output? (BTW: your `dput`ed data doesn't match your first data.frame. Is there something else going on here?)

Comment: @r2evans yes, forgot about it.

Comment: @r2evans - i've edited the original question to include the expected output
And sorry about the data, I created two separate files with random numbers for Item ID (I don't have the actual values yet), and forgot to save the one I used in the original question.

Comment: Please update it in your post by editing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# get length of the largest vector
max_cols <- max( unlist( lapply(df1$Col2, length ) ) )

# fill with NA to make it equal length
a1 <- lapply( df1$Col2, function( x ) c( x, rep( NA, ( max_cols - length( x ) ) ) ) ) 

# combine column 1 with transformed data
df1 <- do.call( 'cbind', list( df1$Col1, do.call( 'rbind', a1 ) ) )

# apply column names
colnames( df1 ) <- paste( "Col", 1: (max_cols+1), sep = '' )

# convert to numeric data type
df1 <- data.frame( apply( df1, 2, as.numeric ) )

df1
#     Col1   Col2   Col3   Col4   Col5  Col6
# 1 162840 137089 668552 346129     NA    NA
# 2 162841 442054 479934  58316     NA    NA
# 3 162842 149298 533977 598069     NA    NA
# 4 162843 898134 614982 581007 570515    NA
# 5 162845  93015 252103 639482 226594 64429
# 6 162847 328971 604454 603078     NA    NA
# 7 162849  93774     NA     NA     NA    NA
```

**Data:**

```
df1 <- structure(list(Col1 = c(162840L, 162841L, 162842L, 162843L, 162845L, 162847L, 162849L), 
                      Col2 = structure(list(`1` = c("137089", "668552", "346129"),
                                            `4` = c("442054", "479934", "58316"),
                                            `7` = c("149298", "533977", "598069"),
                                            `10` = c("898134", "614982", "581007", "570515"),
                                            `14` = c("93015", "252103", "639482", "226594", "64429"), 
                                            `19` = c("328971", "604454", "603078"), 
                                            `22` = "93774"), 
                                       .Names = c("1", "4", "7", "10", "14", "19", "22"))),
                 .Names = c("Col1", "Col2"), 
                 row.names = c(NA, -7L), 
                 class = "data.frame")
```